# Digital electronics design

Tags: digital-logic, pinout, nand, circuits

Our professor asked us to name the pins of the gates as below based on a chip pinout diagram he provided which includes only NAND and NOR but in the circuit diagram, there's a negative OR gate.

Can someone please explain how to include pin numbers for it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE - when we see what is apparently a homework question we expect you to have tried to solve it; in this case, I suggest looking up DeMorgan's theorem.

Comment: hi, I tried it. got the simplified boolean expression. I'm just confused as to how to deal with a negative NOR gate when adding the pin numbers to the input and output terminals. does DeMorgan's law come in handy during that? thank you for your input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first sentence of the question is struck out but it tells you that you're looking for 74HX series chips. All of them should be standard but the rightmost one is unusual. Let's draw the logic table for it.

*Table 1. Truth table for the rightmost logic gate.*

```
X  Y  Z
=  =  =
0  0  1
1  0  1
0  1  1
1  1  0
```

Now this should look very familiar as one of the standard logic gates. Can you see which one?

Once you have that then mark your diagram with the chip number(s) you have chosen, look up the pinout, mark them up and post your solution into your question for review.

I think you will find that they have snuck an extra lesson into this exercise for you.

Comment: so when we have an unusual gate (not a standard one) we create a truth table for it and find a common gate with a similar table? and can we use the same numbering of the common gate to number the one in the circuit? like in this circuit i realised its a NAND (thanks to your help!) gate so i used the numbering of that chip for the one present in the circuit? also I'm so sorry if this is a stupid question but we do not replace the unusual gate physically right? solution: https://pasteboard.co/IZEJ2ff.jpg the first diagram is numbered for the given circuit and second one is the equivalent one.

Comment: (1) You should post your image in the question as I suggested. (2) A good designer will be trying to simplify a circuit and use standard gates wherever possible without, for example, only using one gate on a four-gate chip which would be wasteful. (3) You figured out that it was a NAND but what did you draw on your lower schematic? (4) The whole idea is to replace the gate physically - ideally with one you already have. (5) No, your two diagrams are not equivalent. Can you see why?

Comment: @darsha - I'm afraid the teacher added a hidden test - can you actually think about the logic - and you failed it. A question: has your course introduced you to DeMorgan's Theorem? Application of this makes it obvious that the mystery gate is a NAND gate. No need to create a truth table. Furthermore, look at the fact that an output inversion followed by an input inversion cancels the two. This means that you could replace the three gates by two AND gates and an OR - and this would make generating the Boolean Equation really, really easy.

Comment: @Transistor yes sorry i was in a rush. i updated the answer in the question. so during the practical i can use one chip for the complete circuit by replacing the last gate with a NAND gate. but for the circuit in the sheet I number it as it is with pin numbers from a NAND gate in the chip for the answer? because i dont think i can change the diagram printed

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast yes we did DeMorgan's theorem, he just introduced the laws to note down. I'm supposed to number the schematic for the circuit without redrawing the diagram. Therefore, do I use the pin numbers of a NAND gate for the last gate in the circuit? Also does that mean i can use one chip for the practical as there are 4 NAND gates? (I updated my answer in the question, your review will be highly appreciated) Thank you for your feedback!

Comment: You've got it but **add the part number to the schematic**.

Comment: @Transistor Got it. I just need to add 74HC00. Thank you so much for the explanation and patience!

Comment: You're welcome. I'm sorry for the torture but you've figured it out yourself rather than us give you an answer. Don't forget to "accept" the answer to mark it solved - if you're happy to do so!

Comment: @darsha - OK, so look at the last gate and apply DeMorgan's theorem to it. And yes, you've figured it out. And for what it's worth, if you want to impress your professor with your diligence, you can produce the 24 permutations of the gate locations, 8 permutations of the input pins, and 6 permutations of the input labels for a total of 1,152 possible solutions.